# how to assign a numeric value to a variable through text box in vb6

Tags: vb6

I have a variable in the vb script , x and I want to change the current value of the variable while running exe. application.

I want to use an a text box and a button so that no matter which numeric value i enter will be entered in the text box, it will assign to the variable X.

Comment: Please revise your question, please remember that you should show what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim X as Integer

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    X = Val(Text1.Text)
End Sub
```

But your question looks incomplete. Try to expand what you have and what you want.

Comment: hi, i have to design a form in which no matter what value i will set in text box , variable should take that value. And if i change the value of text box it will take new value.    Eg. initially if X=3 , and then if i put 5 in the text box X will become 5, it will over wright the previous value.

Comment: You should write the same code but in another event, for example Text1_Change() instead Command1_Click()